# System.Diagnostics.Process.HasExited always returns true and Process.Exited event handler always hits when process is still open

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2013

I am currently having issues with a piece of my code. This code works perfectly fine (even without some of the extra if statements) on my machine when I run it both through Visual Studio 2013 and when I publish using ClickOnce. On the client's machine, the event handler for the process exiting catches, the process ID is correct, and the process.hasExited returns true all while the process is still open. The process opens a pdf for them to sign and waits for them to save it and close it before proceeding. It uses Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.

The error message received is from the catch block of the event handler method:

System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

This occurs at the call for getReaders_NewHire(emp).

This is the method that opens the process:

```
private void pdfAndEmail(Employee employee, Requirements requirements)
    {
        try
        {
            PDFUtility pdfu = new PDFUtility();
            pdfu.createPDFMG_NewHire(employee, requirements);

            emp = employee;

            process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            string path = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "\\ITResources\\Manager\\NewHire_" + employee.m_name.Replace(" ", "") + ".pdf";
            Uri pdf = new Uri(path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            process.StartInfo.FileName = pdf.LocalPath;
            process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            process.Exited += new EventHandler(process_Exited);
            process.Start();
            pid = process.Id;
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "Error Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
```

and this is the event handling method:

```
private void process_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (process.Id == pid)
            {
                if (process.HasExited)
                {
                    PDFUtility pdfu = new PDFUtility();
                    pdfu.getReaders_NewHire(emp);

                    Emailer send = new Emailer();
                    send.SendAfterMG_NewHire();
                }
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Process has not exited.", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
```

The getReaders method in the event handler needs to read the file that the client has to sign so it must be closed beforehand. I cannot force a close because I will never know how long it will take them to sign and I can't have the email being sent out before they've signed and saved the pdf.

I've already tried using the WaitForExit() method and it skips completely (only on my client's computer). I am running Windows 10, but the client is running Windows 7. I have not been able to find any documentation about these methods not working on Win7.

Note: I understand that the if statements in the event handler method are a bit redundant, but I was desperate to find where it was catching.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

FIXED: I ended up have a Message Box pop up after my PDF was signed to assist the WaitForExit() in the Background Worker thread. After this message box's OK button is pressed (because they pause the application and wait for a response), it then reads the pdf files.

Comment: How is this related to [tag:wpf]?

Comment: @SirRufo It is a WPF application, my apologies.

Comment: It appears that your Process is just attempting to open the file. Shouldn't you be waiting until the entire file is created from the pdfu.createPDFMG_NewHire call? If the pdfu.createPDFMG_NewHire call is creating the PDF it may not be closing the file handles correctly so when you launch the file to open it technically it is still locked form the creation process.

Comment: @Matt When the pdf is created, the document closes and saves in it's designated location correctly. The process to open the pdf works as well. But before the pdf is ever closed, it hits the exited event handler. The getReaders_NewHire call opens the pdf back up to merge it with another file.

Comment: Have you tried addding process.WaitForExit(); after your process.Start() call?

Comment: @Matt I've tried it by itself and had the same issues. Or do you mean adding it and keeping the exited handler?

Comment: I mean adding it and keeping the Exit handler. It could also be that the process is launching and the executing a secondary process to open another app to show the pdf. If that is the case then it will exit immediately.

Comment: It is not lying to you.  Acrobat Reader is a single-instance app.  Starting it again simply gets the 2nd process to ask the 1st one to open the pdf file.  After which it quits, takes well less than a second.  Nothing much you can do about that, consider FileSystemWatcher.

Comment: So, from the sound of it, I'm going to have to find another way to call my readers method.

Comment: Could you have them sign in your app and then generate the pdf and place the signature image in the pdf after they sign and click a button?

Comment: @Matt I was thinking of something like that originally, but because of how Digital Signatures are done in Adobe, it didn't seem like it was going to work.

Comment: Take a look at iTextSharp library. They have the ability to Digitally Sign the PDF according to the PDF specifiation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I ended up just calling it in the original background worker thread after another method to give the pdf time to be created, then signed, then closed.

Answer (score 0):

> It uses Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.

This is your advantage I think, and my approach assumes this. Consider the following:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("AcroRd32").FirstOrDefault();
    if (process != null)
    {
        Process.Start(@"C:\mvvm.pdf");
    }
    else
    {
        process = Process.Start(@"C:\mvvm.pdf");
    }
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.Exited += (sender, args) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exited");
    };

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

First we check if Adobe process is already running, if so we keep the reference and hook the event handler to that existing process. If not we do what you have already done. Some validation code is omitted.

I have tested with the process running and not running and it works.

**NOTICE: It will not work as expected if the user has another application configured as a predefined PDF reader**